# Unit Testing an Angular Directive that Uses ngModel

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

I am currently writing unit tests for an app I have been working on, but I am unsure of how to handle this case. How does one create a `spyOn` function for `ngModel.$validate()`?

```
let moduleName = 'compareTo';

// ## Directive Definition
class compareTo {

  constructor() {

    this.restrict = 'EA';
    this.require = 'ngModel';
    this.scope = { otherModelValue : '=compareTo' };
  }

  // ### Optional Link Function
  link (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

    ngModel.$validators.compareTo = (modelValue) => {

      return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
    };

    scope.$watch('otherModelValue', () => {

      // I am trying to spy on this function call.
      ngModel.$validate();
    });
  }
}

export default [moduleName, directiveFactory(compareTo)];
```

I am trying to write a test like so:

```
describe('link function', () => {

  it('should', () => {

    spyOn(/* not sure what should go here? */, '$validate');
  });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than create a `spyOn` function for `$validate()`, I went about testing the functionality of `scope.$watch` in the `link` function by using the form controller to directly manipulate what to pass for directives. See this test:

```
describe('link function', () => {

    let password = 'nerfherder';

    let confirmPassword = 'nerfherder';

    it('should validate with matching passwords', () => {

        form.password.$setViewValue(password);

        form.confirmPassword.$setViewValue(confirmPassword);

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect($rootScope.user.password)
            .toBe(password);

        expect($rootScope.user.confirmPassword)
            .toBe(confirmPassword);

        expect(form.password.$valid).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should not validate with passwords that do not match', () => {

        confirmPassword = 'badpassword';

        form.password.$setViewValue(password);

        form.confirmPassword.$setViewValue(confirmPassword);

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect($rootScope.user.password)
            .toBe(password);

        expect($rootScope.user.confirmPassword)
            .toBeUndefined();

        expect(form.confirmPassword.$valid).toBe(false);
    });
});
```